# How to print the old value and interpolated value from dfs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a `df` named `so` as follows:

```
      gas day    RLM       Date
0   22.03.2020  5501593 2020-03-22
1   23.03.2020  9232167 2020-03-23
2   24.03.2020  8807847 2020-03-24
3   25.03.2020  8561604 2020-03-25
4   26.03.2020  7775652 2020-03-26
5   27.03.2020  56022577 2020-03-27
6   28.03.2020  4556959 2020-03-28
7   29.03.2020  5233497 2020-03-29
8   30.03.2020  8181341 2020-03-30
9   31.03.2020  8063470 2020-03-31
```

The user can select a few values from the `RLM` column and those values have to be replaced with a `NaN` and interpolated. For that I am doing:

```
def spline_interpolate(data: pd.DataFrame,
                       to_replace: list,
                       measure: str = 'RLM'):
    data_interpolation = data.copy()
    data_interpolation[measure] = data_interpolation[measure].replace(
        to_replace, np.nan)
    data_interpolation[measure] = data_interpolation[measure].interpolate(method='spline',
                                                                          order=3)
    return data_interpolation
```

Then, I do:

```
so_interpolation = spline_interpolate(so, [56022577])
```

After interpolating, the `so_interpolation` is:

```
      gas day     RLM         Date
0   22.03.2020  5501593.0   2020-03-22
1   23.03.2020  9232167.0   2020-03-23
2   24.03.2020  8807847.0   2020-03-24
3   25.03.2020  8561604.0   2020-03-25
4   26.03.2020  7775652.0   2020-03-26
5   27.03.2020  5979531.5   2020-03-27
6   28.03.2020  4556959.0   2020-03-28
7   29.03.2020  5233497.0   2020-03-29
8   30.03.2020  8181341.0   2020-03-30
9   31.03.2020  8063470.0   2020-03-31
```

Now, I would like to know if there is a way where I can print a statement automatically that says that the value(s) to be replaced (from the `to_replace` list) have been replaced by `xxxxxxx` value?

**Example:**

In the above example, the value `56022577` is interpolated as `5979531.5`.

I would like to add a `print` statement in the `spline_interpolation()` function that automatically prints the old value and the new interpolated value:

```
print('The value 56022577 is interpolated as 5979531.5')
```

**P.S.**: `to_replace` in the `spline_interpolation()` function can take multiple values as all those values have to be replaced with `NaN`s and subsequently interpolated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would modify the function:

```
def spline_interpolate(data,
                       to_replace,
                       measure = 'RLM'):
    data_interpolation = data.copy()
    data_interpolation[measure] = data_interpolation[measure].replace(
        to_replace, np.nan)

    # where replacements occur
    s = data_interpolation[measure].isna()

    data_interpolation[measure] = data_interpolation[measure].interpolate(method='spline',
                                                                          order=3)

    # print as required
    for orig,rep in zip(data.loc[s,measure], data_interpolation.loc[s,measure]):
        print(f'The value {orig} is interpolated as {rep}')
    return data_interpolation
```